# Phpmyadmin not displaying table data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, config

I have a table named "log", which basically stores error log for my php application. My application has database running on rds, and recently i had to delete logs from this table, so i downloaded a backup of this table and imported into my local database in phpmyadmin.

It imported well, but when i went into the table its showed 0 records..
[image]

But there are records as its evident from this image..
[image: there are about 4.2million records]

I just don't know why it isn't displaying the records, even if they are there..is this has anything to do with large number of records..i tried to search it but couldn't find it..please help..

thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you imported the `logs` table into this database? Did you use the `use \`databasename\`;` before doing the import?

Comment: Try renaming the Table from `log` to something else. It might work.

Comment: i have already tried renaming the table name..yes i am sure i have imported it correctly..